# How to use TrimStart(), TrimEnd() properly?

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse something.

```cs
string str = @"UdPbC\0\s:SI0002,d:IC0002,n:234*66$SIACK," + random.Next(4) + "*C4<CR><LF>\r\n";
str = str.TrimStart('$');
Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

It still gives me the same sentence. I want to trim before '$'. How can I use `TrimStart` properly?

Comment: TrimStart and TrimEnd are for removing extra characters such as space from front and end. you need to use SubString and IndexOf method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrimStart()` will only remove whitespaces, if you want to only select a specific section within a string, use `Substring()`

```cs
str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('$'));
```

Comment: `TrimStart` can be used to remove any characters. If you don't specify a character then it will remove whitespace but if you specify one or more characters then it will remove those characters from the beginning of a `String`. `TrimStart('$')` will remove leading dollar signs, not other characters up to the first dollar sign.

Comment: original document states the parameter as char array, thus providing only a char may not work as intended

Comment: @OnurDilek sorry for that. I made a mistake trying to fix your answer. But now it's gone I cannot rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

You might even want to consider [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0):

Enumerating them all:

```
string str = @"UdPbC\0\s:SI0002,d:IC0002,n:234*66$SIACK," + random.Next(4) + "*C4<CR><LF>\r\n";
var data = str.Split('$');

foreach (var s in data)
    Debug.WriteLine(data[0]);
```

or just select the desired element directly:

```
string str = @"UdPbC\0\s:SI0002,d:IC0002,n:234*66$SIACK," + random.Next(4) + "*C4<CR><LF>\r\n";
str = str.Split('$')[1];
Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

Output:

```
SIACK,3*C4<CR><LF>\r\n
```